# How to empty input values and reset state in ReactJS hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, state

Assume I have three inputs and a button, I want to empty input values when button is clicked.

```
 const [input_value,set_input_value] = useState({
     input1:'',
     input2:'',
     input3:''
 })

const inputs_handler = (e) => {
    let name= e.target.name;
    let value= e.target.value;
    input_value[name] = value;

    set_input_value(input_value);
}

const clear_input_values = () => {

  // First try

    /* 
     set_input_value({
       input1:'',
       input2:'',
        input3:''
     }) 
    */


   //SECOND TRY
    set_input_value(prevState => ({ 
    ...prevState,
        input1:'',
        input2:'',
        input3:''
    }))
  // console.log shows that the values of state didn't get empty from the first click, but does in 
     the second
    console.log(input_value)


}

<div>
  <input onChange={inputs_handler} type='text' name='input1' />
  <input onChange={inputs_handler} type='text' name='input2' />
  <input onChange={inputs_handler} type='text' name='input3' />

  <input onClick={clear_input_values} type='submit' />
</div>
```

I can use `document.getElementsById(id)[0].value='';` to empty the input's value but I don't think this is the proper way to do it in a React project.

This is really confusing me, i appreciate if someone provides a clear example or a link to an example that explains how the state works and when it does render the component. since i believe i changed the state value before i use `set_inputvalues()` method.

Comment: you need to bind the input.value to the corresponding piece of state

Comment: @AngelSalazar i did using the handler to get the values, but if i set the input value like this `<input onChange={inputs_handler} type='text' value={input_values.input1} name='input3' />` i woudn't be able to change the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is state object mutation. You are mutating `input_value` and saving it back in state instead of returning a new object reference.

**Updating State**

`set_input_value(input_value);` vs `set_input_value({ ...input_value, [name]: value });`

This spreads in the existing state and sets the key-value pair of the input that was updated.

If the spread syntax is unfamiliar it is a common convention to shallowly copy the state object into a new object. `useState` hooks can also use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), and if you check the link you'll see a note about how `useState` doesn't merge in state updates like it's class-based counterpart, `this.setState()`:

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does
>   not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
>   behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> setState(prevState => {   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

You might notice now that our solution isn't a functional update, but the spread syntax works the same. The reason we can do a standard update is because your state consists of 3 independent variables, and upon each update you copy all of them and then simply replace any one of them.

Functional updates are primarily used when *the next* state value *depends on* the current state value, like the counter examples react loves to use.

I should point out that functional updates are a react convention while the spread syntax is part of javascript's [expressions & operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

**Clearing Inputs**

Your first try is correct for clearing state, so long as you bind the state value to each input.

```
const [input_value, set_input_value] = useState({
  input1: "",
  input2: "",
  input3: ""
});

const inputs_handler = e => {
  let name = e.target.name;
  let value = e.target.value;

  set_input_value({ ...input_value, [name]: value });
};

const clear_input_values = () => {
  set_input_value({
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: ""
  });
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

    <div>
      <input
        onChange={inputs_handler}
        type="text"
        name="input1"
        value={input_value.input1}
      />
      <input
        onChange={inputs_handler}
        type="text"
        name="input2"
        value={input_value.input2}
      />
      <input
        onChange={inputs_handler}
        type="text"
        name="input3"
        value={input_value.input3}
      />

      <input onClick={clear_input_values} type="submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit romantic-hawking-rqvko]

Comment: this cleared the inputs values, but the problem is that it changes the structure of the `input_value` object. please set `console.log(input_values)` in the handler and see how the `input_values` structure is changed when type three letters in the first input

Comment: @AliAlAmine Oof, yes, you are quite right. I updated answer with solution that doesn't change the shape of state.

Comment: just didn't get how this `set_input_value({ ...input_value, [name]: value });` solved it, can you provide a good resource link that explains this in a simple and clear example?

Comment: @AliAlAmine Sure. Updated answer again with some explanation and link to react and javascript docs.